# Database for online shop with many products

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

How do I create a database which contains **many different products of various categories**?
They also have **different attributes**.

My idea is to create 3 tables:

Product (*pid*)

Category (*cid*, parentcategory)

Product_category (*pid, cid*)

I think this manages the categories, but how do i store the attributes efficiently?

Comment: Can a product belong to different categories?

Comment: No, an example for different categories would be: Shirts, Pullover, socks, Accessories

Comment: If you'll never need that, you can skip the Product_category table and instead have a cid column in the product table (foreign key.)

Comment: And let‘s say for example socks is a subcategory of  accessories

Comment: That would be two categories right? How would I store that?

Comment: I'd say store socks only. And run-time find  accessories. (Which will work forever, even if a sub-category is moved to another parent-category.)

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by „run-time“

Comment: You don't store a product's parent category, you select it when needed, via the product's category.

Comment: There are many Q&A discussing things like this.

Comment: Thanks! And another question: Each subcategory has some similar features/ attributes (Shirt eg. has size, color etc.) but some features might be shared by different categories. How do i store that?

Answer (score 0):

If your products will not be in two or more categories, you don't need conenction table.
According to the comment section, I have a suggestion for you:

If and only if you decide to store `category` and `sub_category` then you have to implement it like this:

category(id, name)
sub_category(id, name, category_id)
product(id, name, sub_category_id)

With this method every products are aware of what is their subcategory. If we have the subcategory, then we are also able to determine the (main) category of every product.

I hope I could help you. Designing the scheme of the database is a very important step of developing an application.